# Making numeric variable immutable after limit reached

Tags: javascript

I am trying to limit the length of a textbox in a form field once a given number of words or characters (excluding spaces) has been reached.

The trouble I am having is that I can't figure out how to limit the substring max length variable once the upper limit has been reached.

I am using Callable.js (https://sacha.me/Countable/docs/) as the counter script.

```js
var wordL = 3;
    var charL = 18;
    var boxid = 'descr';
    var area = document.getElementById(boxid);
    function fixlength(boxid,wordlimit,charlimit,wordcount,charcount,allcount) {
            if (charcount > charlimit || wordcount > wordlimit) {
                    /******************************
                    * The following line contains the problematic dynamic variable
                    *******************************/
                    area.value = area.value.substring(0, all);                                                                 
            }
    }
    function callback (counter) {
      console.log(counter);
      document.getElementById("wordsleft").innerHTML = wordL - counter.words;
      document.getElementById("charsleft").innerHTML = charL - counter.characters;
      fixlength(boxid,wordL,charL,counter.words,counter.characters,counter.all);
    }
    Countable.live(area, callback);
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RadLikeWhoa/Countable/master/Countable.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  Words:<span id="wordsleft"></span> Chars:<span id="charsleft"></span>
   <form>
     <textarea id="descr" name"descr"></textarea>
     </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you'd need to stop that text area from accepting user input once the limit is reached. If I'm right you should attach an `onKeyPress` event listener to that text area in which once that limit is exceeded, you should `return false`. Returning false means stopping the text area from accepting new characters.

- HTML

  ```
  <textarea id="descr" name"descr" onKeyPress="return keyPressHandler()" ></textarea>
  ```
- JavaScript

  ```
  function keyPressHandler(){
      if(/* limit is reached */){
          return false;
      }
  }
  ```

Demo:

```js
function handle(e, event) {
  if (event.keyCode != 8 && e.value.length > 10) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea onKeyPress="return handle(this, event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: This unfortunately seems to have no effect ?  I've added the caller, checked it returns false with a simple "console.log("here!");" line before the return false line, but it does not actually stop me typing.

Comment: @LittleCode Please see the demo.

Comment: ok, was missing the "return" in the text area. Thank you. But two problems (a) it lets me overrun the limit (e.g. I define 3 words, it lets me type 4 before it blocks).  (b) having blocked me at 4 words, it then prevents me from backspacing to delete the excess characters.

Comment: @LittleCode It's only a simple demo, the rest is up to you `:)`.

Comment: Oh well... I guess you deserve a little green tick anyway, so here you go .... thanks for your help.

Comment: @LittleCode It now supports backspaces my friend! Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested a solution that works for what you are attempting .

Example - Using jQuery

```
$("#id-here").keyup(function(){
```

// Following line removes spaces from string

```
 var characters = $("#id-here").val().replace(/\s/g,'');
```

// Set max length

```
  var max_length = 50;
```

// if statement checks if user input is equal to max length , if so the textarea will get an attribute property of read only which disables the user from entering more text

```
if(characters.length == max_length){

    $("#id-here").attr("readonly","readonly");
  }

});
```

Comment: I am not clear how setting maxlength helps with my defined requirement of "number of words or characters (excluding spaces)" ?